# Auto Import or Auto Complete for Ionic 3 in visual studio code?

Tags: ionic-framework, autocomplete, ionic2

Hello I need to Know which extension is suitable for me to auto complete the ionic tags Like

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

In this ionic tag when I write this code in visual studio then "**stacked**"
Word is not auto-completed also floating, fixed keywords are not auto-completed by visual studio code Please tell me any extension for Ionic 3 auto-completing label tags or all that.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: So In which community i can ask this type of question?

Comment: The [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/) seems like the right place for this question :)

Comment: @sebaferreras thanks i will ask this on Ionic forum.